# Настройка сервера Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, raspberry-pi

хочу поинтересоваться, как мне сделать доступным мой домашний веб сервер из raspberry в интернете, а не только в локальной сети? apache php уже установлены и простейшие сайты без бд работают в локальной сети, но хотелось бы получать к ним доступ хоть откуда, я пока не понимаю в какую сторону копать?

Comment: модель роутера какая?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Купить у провайдера белый IP
2. Организовать проброс портов(80, 443, 22 etc) с Raspberry PI, на домашний маршрутизатор.
3. ???
4. Profit!

Comment: Белый IP купил, а вот с пробросом совершенно не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: @СергейКузнецов Какая у вас модель роутера?

Comment: Для канона ты забыл `?????` какотдельным пунктом перед "profit" вставить.

Comment: @donRumata Точно! :-)

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь, все настроил.

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от вашего роутера. Интересующие вас настройки - port forward и DDNS

При динамическом IP

1. Необходима регистрация аккаунта на noip.com или схожем сервисе DDNS
2. Добавить полученые логин\рароль на ваш роутер в разделе DDNS
3. В разделе port forward выбрать какой внешний порт буд переадрисован на Raspbbery. Положим, Raspbbery 192.168.1.10:80 то перадрисация внешнего порта 80 будет привязана к вашей малине.

Большая часть конкретных действий зависит от типа вашей линии подлючения, роутера\брендмауэра, типа выделеного IP (динамический или статический).

Почитать

- DDNS
- NAT
- DNS